# Ubuntu 18.04 restore backup failed

Tags: backup, restore, 18.04

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 after deleting Ubuntu 17.10,
I created a back up on my usb drive but Ubuntu 18.04 won't restore the files
as it says 
"RESTORE FAILED
Failed to execute child process “duplicity” (No such file or directory)"

I do not have any other copies of my ancient files and those are very important to me, can you help get my files restored, please?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing a new copy of Ubuntu 18.04 you need to install `duplicity` before the files can be restored. Use this command:

```
sudo apt install duplicity
```

Disclaimer: I don't use `duplicity` myself.

Comment: I thought that came pre-installed on Ubuntus?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I'll have to reboot to try 18.04 but typing `$ duplicity`  on 16.04 it says: `The program 'duplicity' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install duplicity`

Comment: Good to know never knew!

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, thank you very much, it solved the problem but now, it says "STORAGE LOCATION NOT AVAILABLE, Waiting for Google to be configured in your backup settings..."

Comment: @HarpartapSC Glad that part got fixed. You'll need to post a new question on the second problem. Be sure to put the "Duplicity - storage location not available, waiting for Google" in the title. Someone who uses Duplicity can tell you how to configure that part.

Answer (score 0):

I did install "duplicity" but it still not works. 
I am not new to Ubuntu and all the previous upgrades, backup and restore work perfectly.